# Order ID generation in database

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently developing an application to allow my users place orders using .NET MVC5 and SQL Server. I have an ID field in my orders table but I want to assign my orders an unique, serial number like P0001, P0002 and so on.

Thing is a user can create an order and delete it before placing it so using the ID column wouldn't satisfy the condition that the order IDs have to be consecutive.

I can select the highest order ID and add 1 everytime I need to generate a new number but that may bring concurrency problems.

I could also create an auxiliary table "order_numbers" with an ID and a random value, I could insert a random value and select the ID number which corresponds to the value I previously inserted to get the unique consecutive number.

My question is: is there a better approach to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how you are implementing everything but redis might solve your concurrency problems. Check out redis.io

Comment: Another option is to have a "last order number" column in a single-record "seed" table that gets incremented each time you ask for a new one.  Then you just append whatever ancillary data you need when you insert into the table.  It's how "auto-increment" keys were done before it was baked into SQL Server.

Comment: One approach is to split this into two entities, Orders and ShoppingCarts. Then your Orders table guarantees an order was placed since only a 'Place Order' button click inserts into the table. If it was cancelled after being ordered you could track that in the same table too. If it is cancelled while ordering (closing browser, 'Cancel' button, etc.), it just remains in the shopping cart.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help!